# Pictures in drupal classified website

Tags: drupal

Hi I am doing a classifieds website I need help with this, I want to put a picture by default when the user that is posting an ad don't have a picture for example that when you post an ad and you don't have picture the system by default shows a picture that says not picture available or something like that like gumtree I cant find this option in drupal 7, please someone could help me with that? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The **image Field** type gives you the ability to upload a default image on its settings page (http://yoursite/admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields/field_testimage).

You can upload default images for each image field you configure.

The only thing it does not do rotate through a set of images. It's only one default image for everyone who does not upload an image.